# DotNetZip changing national letters

Tags: c#

When I create an archive with DotNetZip it changes national letters in files names to their English equivalents. (Ł --> L) It's really bad in my case as breaks my backup app. I tried to change encoding to utf8, 1252, but it failed. How to fix this?

Comment: Sadly, yesterday I saw an answer I'd made to a question here being referenced on the web when someone was similarly mangling text into less human-readable ASCII for no good reason :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Faq, it should handle letters other than the 26 in English:

**Can the library be used to read a zip file that has entries with filenames containing Chinese characters, produced by WinRAR?**

Yes. To do this you would specify the "big5" code page (cp 950) when reading the zip. In addition to Chinese, it can handle any code page.

**What about reading and writing zip files with other languages and code pages? Portugese? Hebrew? Arabic? Greek? Cyrillic? Norwegian? Finnish? etc?**

Yes. Just specify the appropriate code page when reading or writing the zip archive.

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/